# Function returns only 1 array result

Tags: php

I' am trying this for a long time now. The function below returns only 1 result where as it should return 3 results.

I have checked the database, the database returns results in a loop fine that means database part is okay, its somewhere in the function that am doing wrong.

```
//function that generates the URI from the database
function generate_uri( $menu_id = 0, $array = '' ){
    global $db;
    $array = array();
    if( !empty($menu_id) ){
        $db->where('menu_id', $menu_id);
        $menu = $db->ObjectBuilder()->getOne('menu');
        $menu_parent = $menu->menu_parent;
        $menu_slug = $menu->menu_slug;
        $array[] = $menu_slug;
        generate_uri($menu_parent, $array);
    }
    return $array;
}

//Calling the function with a parameter of 3
var_dump(generate_uri(3));
```

**Output**

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "photo-gallery-1" }
```

**Should Return**

```
 array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "photo-gallery-1" [1]=> string(12) "photo-gallery" [2]=> string(9) "resources"}
```

Comment: Did u try to this print_r(generate_uri(3));? instead of var_dump

Comment: @Grald yes I have tried it, still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the function, you set `$array` empty:
    `$array = array();`
Another problem is that you are not getting the return of the function inside the if statement. Change this line:

```
generate_uri($menu_parent, $array);
```

To this:

```
$array = generate_uri($menu_parent, $array);
```

So, the function should be something like this:

```
function generate_uri($menu_id = 0, $array = '') {
  global $db;

  if (!empty($menu_id)) {
    $db->where('menu_id', $menu_id);
    $menu = $db->ObjectBuilder()->getOne('menu');
    $menu_parent = $menu->menu_parent;
    $menu_slug = $menu->menu_slug;
    $array[] = $menu_slug;
    $array = generate_uri($menu_parent, $array);
  }

  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You're redeclaring `$array` at each recursive call, so it gets reinitialised each time. Try declaring it before calling `generate_uri()` and passing it as the second argument:

```
$array = array();
var_dump(generate_uri(3, $array));
```

And don't forget to remove it from inside the function.